# Gravar no oracle sem repetir nome

Tags: oracle, asp

Tenho esse bloco dentro de uma procedure que grava um representante, que vem de uma tela em ASP Clássico.

```
v_qtd_rep := ts_obtem_dados_no_xml(v_no_completo,'QTD_REP');

            for i in 1..v_qtd_rep loop

            --delete from prestador_representante where cod_prestador_ts = v_COD_PRESTADOR_TS;

            v_COD_PRESTADOR_TS   := ts_obtem_dados_no_xml(v_no_completo,'COD_PRESTADOR_TS');
            v_NOME_REPRESENTANTE := ts_obtem_dados_no_xml(v_no_completo,'NOME_REP_' || i);
            v_DDD_REPRESENTANTE  := ts_obtem_dados_no_xml(v_no_completo,'DDD_REP_' || i);
            v_TEL_REPRESENTANTE  := ts_obtem_dados_no_xml(v_no_completo,'TEL_REP_' || i);
            v_ID_REPRESENTANTE   := ts_obtem_dados_no_xml(v_no_completo,'ID_REPRESENTANTE_' || i);

            select prestador_representante_seq.nextval into vId from dual;

            --select nom_representante from ts.prestador_representante where cod_prestador_ts = v_COD_PRESTADOR_TS;

            --if v_ID_REPRESENTANTE is null then

              if v_NOME_REPRESENTANTE is not null and v_DDD_REPRESENTANTE is not null and v_TEL_REPRESENTANTE is not null and v_ID_REPRESENTANTE is null then
                      insert into ts.prestador_representante(id_representante, cod_prestador_ts, nom_representante, ddd_representante, tel_representante, dt_atu, cod_usuario_atu)
                                                       values(vId, v_COD_PRESTADOR_TS, v_NOME_REPRESENTANTE , v_DDD_REPRESENTANTE, v_TEL_REPRESENTANTE, sysdate, v_cod_usuario);
              --end if;
            /*else
              update prestador_representante set nom_representante = v_NOME_REPRESENTANTE, ddd_representante = v_DDD_REPRESENTANTE, tel_representante = v_TEL_REPRESENTANTE
                     where cod_prestador_ts = v_COD_PRESTADOR_TS;    */   
            end if;

            end loop;
            commit;
```

Os campos que tem o nome,ddd e tel são dinâmicos. Um botão vai adicionando campos na tela. Uma função `ASP` pega os dados da tela, transforma em um `XML` e envia para o `ORACLE`. O que passa que quando eu abro a tela e digamos ela possui 3 registros, que são mostrados na tela. Se mando processar, ela se transforma em 5 e se processo novamente vaia para 9 e assim por diante. Ela não repete o primeiro registro e não me perguntem, pois não tenho a mínima idéia porque disso. Como eu faço, no código acima para não gravar o mesmo nome. As linhas comentadas, são as minhas tentativas de fazer funcionar, fora as já deletadas. No aguardo.

Answer (score 1):

pnet,

Você está fazendo um insert, então os registro vão sempre aumentar mesmo. Veja que quando você obtém os dados do XML, na última linha, você trás um v_ID_REPRESENTANTE, mas, logo abaixo, você vai na sequência prestador_representante_seq e trás um novo id, que é armazenado em vId.

Não entendi exatamente o que você quer fazer, mas suponho que trocar este Insert por um Update deva resolver.

Comment: Alysson, isso já foi uma outra tentativa para não gravar. Eu ao postar, não apaguei, para mostrar a vocês o que eu já fiz. Em realidade o vId é o correto, pois eu pego na sequence e gravo na PK. O que eu quero é quando eu der um Insert, já ter a certeza que não está indo valores já repetido. Pelo visto, vou tentar tratar na tela, mas não seria o correto. O correto seria no banco, na própria `PROC`.

Comment: pnet, entendi, você só quer inserir se não tiver o valor na tabela. Neste caso você deverá fazer um SELECT como na linha que vc comentou, algo assim:

Comment: SELECT nom_representante INTO vNOME FROM ts.prestador_representante WHERE cod_prestador_ts = v_COD_PRESTADOR_TS;

Comment: Alysson, dessa forma dá erro, pois eu posso ter vários nomes na tabela e o into vai se perder, pois ele aceita apenas um. Agora veio a idéia de um count e colocar na var. Da forma acima eu fiz e não funfou.